# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Chapter 8.3 - website form showing twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am currently following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and have run into a slight issue after completing [section 8.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-cucumber) in the tutorial.  Functionally, everything works fine, I am able to add users through my form and everything.  However, now my forms are showing up twice on every page of the website.  I have gone over the code multiple times and just cannot figure out what is causing this to happen.  Here is a link to my Heroku site where you can see the issue: http://deep-mist-5284.heroku.com/

When I run the website in rails server it outputs these files that it is using, but I have looked through these and haven't found anything wrong.

```
Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-05 16:43:13 -0700
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (17.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (10.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.6ms)
Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (280.3ms)
```

Does anybody have any idea what is causing this issue?

UsersController
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @user.password = ""
      @user.password_confirmation = ""
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Shared/_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
    <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

Layouts/_header.html.erb

```
<header>
  <%= link_to logo, root_path %>
  <nav class="round">
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Layouts/_footer.html.erb

```
<footer>
  <nav class="round">
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
      <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Rails Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

layouts/application

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <section class="round">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
        <% end %> 
        <%= yield %>
      </section>
      <section class="round">
        <%= yield %>
      </section>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two <%= yield %> in your layouts/application.html.erb. You're having Rails put the contents of users/new.html.erb (and every other page as well) into your layouts/application.html.erb twice. Remove one and all will be fixed.